# PHP MYSQL prevent getting duplicate unique id while inserting from different users at same time

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to generate invoice id in each invoice, now i am  having thousands of invoices, Now while adding from different ip same time i am getting duplicate invoice ids how to prevent it,

> invoice id generating by getting the last inserted invoice id and increment 1 to it.

**my function as follows parameters**

```
get_new_tbl_id('table_name','invoice_id_column','string to strip (INV in INV0012)','any conditions');

function get_new_tbl_id($tbl_name,$id_field,$string,$options='')
{
$new_id = 0;
$query_count_rows = "SELECT MAX(CONVERT(replace(replace($id_field,',',''),'$string',''), SIGNED INTEGER)) as $id_field FROM $tbl_name WHERE $id_field LIKE '$string%'  $options";
$count_rows = mysql_query($query_count_rows);
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($count_rows);
if($num_rows >0)
{
$last_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($count_rows);
$last_id = $last_row[$id_field];
$last_inserted_id = intval(str_replace($string,'',$last_id));
$new_id = $last_inserted_id+1;
}
else
$new_id = 1;
$format = '%1$03d';
$new_id=sprintf($format,$new_id,'');
return $string.$new_id;
}
```

My table as follows

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tbl_invoice` (
  `invoice_tbl_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `invoice_time` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `invoice_ip` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `invoice_status` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `invoice_added_by` smallint(6) NOT NULL,
  `invoice_edited_by` smallint(6) NOT NULL,
  `invoice_date` date NOT NULL,
  `invoice_id` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `customer_id` varchar(11) NOT NULL,
  `invoice_credit_date` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `invoice_credit_status` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `total_items_count` smallint(6) NOT NULL,
  `invoice_total_amount` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `invoice_grandtotal_amount` double NOT NULL,
  `invoice_discount` double NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `invoice_total_card_amount` double NOT NULL,
  `invoice_total_cash_amount` double NOT NULL,
  `invoice_total_profit` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `cashier_approval` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `cashier_approval_id` smallint(6) NOT NULL,
  `cashier_approval_time` datetime NOT NULL,
  `cashier_approval_ip` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `invoice_delete_note` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`invoice_tbl_id`),
  KEY `invoice_id` (`invoice_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Comment: Insert the table without invoice_id at first and update the invoice_id using table row id.

Comment: you dont have auto increament primary key in table???

Comment: ehm.. where is the primary key?

Comment: **primary key is there** in the table if i add a invoice the primary key will be 1 and **editing the invoice add a new row**, if i edit the invoice wise 2 rows will be inserted with status  2, In the that case if i add new invoice the new id will be 4 i need 2

Answer (score 0):

Use a myisam table to generate the ids for you with 2 fields. The 1st field contains the prefix (this is $string in your function), the second should be an auto increment field. Add a primary key on these 2 fields, but the prefix field **must be the 1st one in the index**. If you insert a new row into this table with a prefix, then mysql will increment the auto increment value within that group.

See myisam notes section in mysql documentation on [auto increment](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-auto-increment.html) for details and example.

```
CREATE TABLE animals (
    grp ENUM('fish','mammal','bird') NOT NULL,
    id MEDIUMINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (grp,id)
) ENGINE=MyISAM;

INSERT INTO animals (grp,name) VALUES
    ('mammal','dog'),('mammal','cat'),
    ('bird','penguin'),('fish','lax'),('mammal','whale'),
    ('bird','ostrich');
```

If your base table is mysql, then just alter it to get this behaviour, if not, then create a separate myisam table, do the inserts into that one first, then obtain the ids fo use in your main table.

Answer (score 0):

May there will be some optimized solution, but for now I can give you this solution

use `static variable lock` if one person is getting id make `$lock=true` and keep other requests on waiting for 1 second and check again by `goto start;` until first request is completed; make `$lock=false;` at the end to release the function.

```
public static $lock=false;

function get_new_tbl_id($tbl_name,$id_field,$string,$options='')
{
    global $lock;
    start:
    if($lock==true){
        sleep(1);
        goto start;
    }

    if($lock==false){
        $lock==true;
    }

    $new_id = 0;
    $query_count_rows = "SELECT MAX(CONVERT(replace(replace($id_field,',',''),'$string',''), SIGNED INTEGER)) as $id_field FROM $tbl_name WHERE $id_field LIKE '$string%'  $options";
    $count_rows = mysql_query($query_count_rows);
    $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($count_rows);
    if($num_rows >0)
    {
    $last_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($count_rows);
    $last_id = $last_row[$id_field];
    $last_inserted_id = intval(str_replace($string,'',$last_id));
    $new_id = $last_inserted_id+1;
    }
    else
    $new_id = 1;
    $format = '%1$03d';
    $new_id=sprintf($format,$new_id,'');

    $lock=false;

    return $string.$new_id;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, **does it work if different users add invoice at same time**

Comment: hope so, try it and let us now

Comment: I tried it, But some times it fires duplicate id for different users inserting at a time.